# Would the structural engineer be liable for this?

Tags: liability, damages

Let's say that I have a structural engineer come to my house to determine if I can remove one of the support posts from the basement. He then determines that I don't need both posts as they are so close together. If I remove the post and over time there are issues with the house due to sagging or other structural issues, is the structural engineer liable for damages because he gave me incorrect information?

Assume I have his "recommendation" in writing and the damages are clearly from the removal of one of the posts.

Answer (score 5):

If he is a professional engineer, then he is almost certainly (supposed to be) licensed and insured.  You could probably recover damages simply by reporting them to his insurer.  Also, some states have insurance pools that provide for claims against professionals that they license.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could sue for breach of contract and/or negligent misstatement.